# findRooms by name or email address

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Using the Microsoft Graph API, I would like to find rooms by either name or email address, such as:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findRooms?$filter=startswith(mail,'cal_')
```

or

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findRooms?$filter=startswith(name,'Building 1')
```

Our rooms are not in RoomLists, and there are well over 100 rooms.

How can I query for a specific, or subset of rooms?

Comment: Martin, please make sure you accept this answer, to help signpost it better for Google searchers.

Answer (score 6):

The API is very limited in beta, and doesn't support OData query parameters like `$filter`. Let the team know how you feel about it :) https://officespdev.uservoice.com/.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I added [this feature request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32524879-findrooms-by-name-or-email-address).

Comment: is there any update on this feature request? I also need to search the rooms with search text.