# findRooms API limit of 100 rooms

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

The `/findRooms` API states:

> "You can get up to the first 100 rooms in the tenant".

Is there a way to increase this limit?

I tried `/findRooms?$top=1000&$count=true` but I am not able to make these query parameters work with `findRooms`.

As stated in [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541711/findrooms-by-name-or-email-address), I am not able to get `$filter` to work either.

Answer (score 3):

The API doesn't currently support things like `$top` or `$skip`. While I cannot make any promises, I would expect that those will get implemented before the API moves out of beta :).

You might want to log it at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/ just to make sure the engineering team hears the feedback.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I just added [this feature request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32525113-add-pagination-to-the-findrooms-api-to-get-past-t).

Comment: Hi Jason, I submitted two feature requests to the officespdev.uservoice.com site, and am not hearing anything back from Microsoft. Is this just a "wish list", or how can I determine if anything will ever come of it?

Comment: It is just a wish list essentially, though our PM team goes through it regularly to look for feedback, etc. They *might* respond on the feature request, but they may not. Rest assured the request will be seen though.

Comment: Thanks, can you give any timeline to when the Graph API will move from beta to v2? The findRooms call is only in beta (vs V1), and I am trying to get a sense if it is still open for expansion, and if so, when that might be?

Comment: No sorry, I don't have any timelines to share on that.

Comment: That [feature request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32525113-add-pagination-to-the-findrooms-api-to-get-past-t) seems to have been deleted ([the link](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32525113-add-pagination-to-the-findrooms-api-to-get-past-t) returns a 404). Is there any other way of getting the full list of rooms beyond the first 100?

Comment: Hey Zach, it got moved. The Graph team migrated to their own UserVoice, you can find it [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/32525113-add-pagination-to-the-findrooms-api-to-get-past-t).